# v-for treat single object the same as collection of objects

Tags: vue.js, v-for

I have an object (let's call it `employments`) like

```
{
 StartDate: "2018-01-01",
 Name: "Chris"
}
```

Sometimes `employments` will be a collection of objects like:

```
{
 StartDate: "2018-01-01",
 Name: "Chris"
},
{
 StartDate: "2017-01-01",
 Name: "Adam Brown"
}
```

If I iterate like this

```
<div v-for="employment in employments">
    <p>{{employment.StartDate}}</p>
    <p>{{employment.Name}}</p>
</div>
```

The keys given (e.g. `employment.StartDate`) in the first object example will fail because the v-for will iterate through the keys of the object instead of the object as a whole. The second collection of objects will work correctly.

***How can I force v-for to treat both objects given in the example the same?***

Comment: It's possible to work around this in Vue - but it's better to normalize your data in your view model and not in your template. That is do `employments = Array.isArray(employments) ? employments : [employments]` in the model side.

Comment: Where are you getting the data from? Is it hard coded? It doesn't look to be valid json you are getting from a backend like php or nodejs. You would need to turn the objects into an array

Comment: @TrevorVarwig an API I wrote in PHP. But these are just typed out for a minimal example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't force `v-for` to treat an object as an array; You need to convert your data to proper format before iterating through it; A type check could be an option:

```
v-for="employment in (Array.isArray(employments) ? employments : [employments])"
```